# Есть ли какой либо виджет для Django наподобие GridView в Yii2

Tags: python, django

Изучаю питон. Уже давно работаю с Yii2, там есть замечательная вещь как GridView, есть ли что то подобное в джанго? Как вообще правильно выводить табличные данные с пагинацией в джанго? Есть ли виджеты или библиотеки для этого?